# meta-toolchain-qt5 on yocto zeus, gcc-cross-canatian-aarch64 fail

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling, yocto, arm64

I'm trying to cross compile C++ application during yocto image building. I'm working on `yocto zeus` with meta-tegra and machine is `Jetson Nano`.
At the beginning I've tried to just add `inherit populate_sdk_qt5` and do task `do_populate_sdk`. It seems to be ok but after shell script running there were no `qmake` on destination location (`/opt/poky`)

Another way I'm trying is to have it done by `bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5`. Unfortunately I face another issue. I cannot resolve following error:

```
NOTE: recipe packagegroup-cross-canadian-jetson-nano-1.0-r0: task do_package_write_ipk: Succeeded
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/lto1 contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/lto1 contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/lto1 contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/lto1 contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/lto1 contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_4.2.0)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/lto1 contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.3)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/lto-wrapper contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/plugin/gengtype contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/plugin/gengtype contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/plugin/gengtype contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/plugin/gengtype contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/plugin/gengtype contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libstdc++.so.6()(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/plugin/gengtype contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libm.so.6()(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/plugin/gengtype contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/plugin/gengtype contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libc.so.6()(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/lto1 contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.4)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-gcov-tool contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.3)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/lto1 contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/lto1 contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/lto1 contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/lto1 contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/lto1 contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libgmp.so.10()(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/lto1 contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libdl.so.2()(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/lto1 contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libz.so.1()(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/libcp1plugin.so.0.0.0 contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/libcp1plugin.so.0.0.0 contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.8)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/libcc1.so.0.0.0 contained in package gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64 requires libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA run found fatal errors. Please consider fixing them.
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/fuji/safeway-by-sternkraft/build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64/7.3.0-r0/temp/log.do_package_qa.16715
NOTE: recipe gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0: task do_package_qa: Failed
ERROR: Task (/home/fuji/safeway-by-sternkraft/build/../meta-tegra/contrib/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-cross-canadian_7.3.bb:do_package_qa) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: recipe gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64-7.3.0-r0: task do_package_write_ipk: Succeeded
```

Do you have any idea how to resolve it? Maybe do you have some tip how to have my c++ binaries n device in other way?

Im working on `Fedora 30` and it used to work, without cross compiling.

Thanks!

Comment: You need the 64-bit libraries. My crystal ball says you only have the 32-bit versions.

Comment: where do I need them? I have to add them to yocto or my fedora? How to do it?

Comment: You need to have the libraries available on the machine where you're compiling. Since you're compiling for ARM64, you'd need the ARM64 libraries on your Fedora machine.

Comment: But my fedora is 64 bit. `Linux fedora 5.0.9-301.fc30.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Apr 23 23:57:35 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Why would that matter? The 64-bit libraries used by the linker are *architecture-specific*. You are building using `gcc-cross-canadian-aarch64`, so you need libraries that match (ARM64). If you're using a cross-compiler, this proves that your Fedora machine is not an ARM64 (as does the string that you just posted in a comment: it's x86-64).

Comment: but this lib is already available on `/opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6`

I've added `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/poky/3.0.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update your zeus branch. There was an update recently. In [this patch](https://github.com/madisongh/meta-tegra/commit/d6ce4c542c151f9bb9c0c701392794a2f2045770)